# Weird characters at the end of char array C

Tags: arrays, c, null-terminated

I've tried to write an [implementation](https://pastebin.com/fw9GA7Gd) of the [Weasel Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program). I have compiled three versions, all exactly identical, with the names "weasel.exe", "weasel2.exe", and "weasel3.exe". "weasel.exe" produces the expected output,

```
Gen 0: YPSZNCWPSDUMLYKRIKNSEOJCERIL
Gen 10: YPSZNCWPSDUMLYKRIKNSE JCERIL
Gen 92: YPSZNCKPSDUMLYKRIKNSE JCERIL
Gen 129: YPSZNCKPSDUMLYKRIKNSE JCEREL
Gen 240: YPSZICKPSDUMLYKRIKNSE JCEREL
Gen 388: YPSZICKPSDTMLYKRIKNSE JCEREL
Gen 570: YPSZICKPSDTMLYKRIKNSE JEEREL
Gen 634: YPSZICKPSDTMLYKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1102: YPSZICKPSDTMLSKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1185: YPSZICKPYDTMLSKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1223: YESZICKPYDTMLSKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1491: YESZICKPYITMLSKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1613: YESZICKPYITMISKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1627: YETZICKPYITMISKRIKN E JEEREL
Gen 1750: YETZICKPYITMISKRIKN E WEEREL
Gen 1855: YETZICKPJITMISKRIKN E WEEREL
Gen 2461: METZICKPJITMISKRIKN E WEEREL
Gen 2536: METZICKPJITMIS RIKN E WEEREL
Gen 2876: METZICKPJITMIS JIKN E WEEREL
Gen 3354: METZICKPJITMIS JIKN E WEAREL
Gen 3668: METZICKPJITMIS JIKN E WEASEL
Gen 3837: METZINKPJITMIS JIKN E WEASEL
Gen 3938: METZINKP ITMIS JIKN E WEASEL
Gen 4147: METHINKP ITMIS JIKN E WEASEL
Gen 4314: METHINKP ITMIS JIKE E WEASEL
Gen 4803: METHINKP ITMIS JIKE A WEASEL
Gen 5441: METHINKP ITMIS LIKE A WEASEL
Gen 6090: METHINKS ITMIS LIKE A WEASEL
Gen 7712: METHINKS IT IS LIKE A WEASEL
```

but "weasel2.exe" produces this

```
Gen 896:  CB FNEOJWT WAVACDESTKWELIEF/c PnW~lcÏ
Gen 897:  CB FNEOJWT WAVACDESTKWELIEF
Gen 981:  CP FNEOJWT WAVACDESTKWELIEF
Gen 1014:  CP FNEOJWT WAVLCDESTKWELIEFOWSE'•&E
Gen 1015:  CP FNEOJWT WAVLCDESTKWELIEF
Gen 1087:  CP FNEOJWT WAVLCDESTKWELSEF/c PnW~lcÏ
```

where there are additional undesired characters at the end of the array. For some generations, this includes parts of what looks like my PATH environment variable. From what I've read on other SO questions this is because there is no "\0" character at the end of the arrays, but when I add

```
[Line 75] offspring[i][28] = '\0';
```

to the offspring allocate loop the program crashes with a memory access violation. The lowest index that would even allow being written to was 8. "weasel2.exe" runs forever, and while some characters do match the weasel string, the others continue to change indefinitely, even if they do manage to 'evolve' into the right character. "weasel3.exe" crashes with a memory access violation every time. When compiling I get these warnings:

> weasel2.c:85: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
> weasel2.c:89: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

But as far as I can tell this is not the cause of the problem (but I'm also probably wrong).

What is causing this, and why does the behaviour only vary between compilations, not tests of each individual program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int randomNumber(int high) {
    return rand() % high;
}

int generateOffspring(char* currentGen, int currentLen, char* letters, char** offspring, unsigned long children, int probability) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < currentLen; c++) {
            if (randomNumber(probability) < 1) {
                offspring[i][c] = letters[randomNumber(27)];
            }
            else {
                offspring[i][c] = currentGen[c];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int findLeastDistance(char* string, char** strings, int len, int count) {
    unsigned int matches = 0;
    unsigned int bestMatches = 0;
    unsigned int bestMatch = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < len; c++) {
            if (string[c] == strings[i][c]) {
                matches++;
            }
        }

        if (matches > bestMatches) {
            bestMatches = matches;
            bestMatch = i;
        }

        matches = 0;
    }

    return bestMatch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("PAUSE");
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    unsigned int probability;

    if (argc == 2) {
        probability = (int)argv[1];
    }
    else {
        probability = 10000;
    }

    unsigned int children = 100;

    char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
    char target[] = "METHINKS IT IS LIKE A WEASEL";
    char currentGen[29];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
        currentGen[i] = letters[randomNumber(27)];
    }

    char** offspring[children];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        offspring[i] = malloc(29);
    }

    unsigned int bestMutation;
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    
    for (;;) {
        generateOffspring(currentGen, 28, letters, offspring, children, probability);

        bestMutation = findLeastDistance(target, offspring, 28, children);

        if (strcmp(currentGen, offspring[bestMutation])) {
            printf("Gen %d: %s\n", counter, offspring[bestMutation]);
        }

        strcpy(currentGen, offspring[bestMutation]);

        if (!strcmp(currentGen, target)) {
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        free(offspring[i]);
    }

    free(currentGen);

    printf("\nEnd\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code may **not** be in a pastebin, it **must** be in the question.

Comment: ..and it should be in a form of [mcve]. If you are getting access violation on `offspring[i][28] = '\0';` then your `i` or `28` is out of bounds of this array, so you need to debug it.

Comment: My compiler spits out 7 warnings but your question does not mention any of them either... :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have tried running the program printing `i` but it never goes above 0, the access violation happens on the first iteration. I cannot see a reason 28 would be out of bounds for an array of size 29, but how should I debug this?

Comment: ... one of the warnings being "weasel.c:102:5: warning: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘currentGen’ [-Wfree-nonheap-object]"...

Comment: @Antti Haapala Sorry, I got only 2 warnings, I will add them to the question.

Comment: It *is* possible that changing the name changes the behaviour. To prove that you'd need to rename weasel2 to weasel and see if it behaves like the weasel.exe did :D

Comment: you did not null-terminate currentGen...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah, I forgot about that, thank you. I have tried compiling again though and the output is the same.

Comment: As for the warnings you should try to deduce **why** they are there. In this case the type of `char** offspring[children];` is wrong.

Comment: This is not how you read an integer from command line: `probability = (int)argv[1];`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks, that fixes the warnings, but the output is still the same

Comment: You should run your code line by line in a debugger, watching the variables in the course. It will be enlightening for sure. -- If you don't know how to use a debugger, please consult its documentation. -- The simplest way to debug (without any debugger) is to insert lots of `printf()` statements to follow the control flow and see the values of variables..

Comment: @thebusybee I have a billion `printf()`s printing pretty much every variable, but as far as I can tell everything is as it should be (and sometimes it even works). I think there is most likely some crucial aspect I don't understand and haven't included, I just don't know what.

Comment: `probability = (int)argv[1];` -> `probability = atoi(argv[1]);` thus removing any undefined behavior that might occur here: `generateOffspring(currentGen, 28, letters, offspring, children, probability);` and beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, change your `generateOffspring` loop as follows:

```
for (unsigned int c = 0; c < currentLen - 1; c++) {
    if (randomNumber(probability) < 1) {
        offspring[i][c] = letters[randomNumber(27)];
    }
    else {
        offspring[i][c] = currentGen[c];
    }
}
offspring[i][currentLen - 1] = 0; // terminate offspring[i]
```

Remember that to store a string N characters long, you need an array that's at least N+1 elements long to store the 0 terminator.

And as Antti Haapala points out, you have the same problem with `currentGen`, so you'll want to change that loop to

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    currentGen[i] = letters[randomNumber(27)];
}
currentGen[28] = 0;
```

Comment: currentGen isn't initialized terminated either. Line 85

Comment: Terminating each string in `generateOffspring` has removed the trailing characters, but now when it reaches the target string it continues regardless.

Comment: Ok, for some reason the `target` string was being modified by the `currentGen` initialisation, but as far as I can tell it works now (haven't been able to break it again).

Comment: There is also a problem with the last argument in the 1st call to  `generateOffspring` where `probability` was initialized with:  `probability = (int)argv[1];`  (this is a first.)